# How to configure PHPDoc indentation for @param descriptions in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting, phpdoc

I'm working with Drupal code in Eclipse Neon, using PDT, and according to [Drupal's PHPDoc conventions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1354#param), I'm supposed to use the `@param` tag something like this:

```
 * @param type $argument
 *   The name and type of an argument. The description can be longer if necessary, 
 *   and if so, you can wrap it to another line.
```

Namely, I'm supposed to write `@param type $argument`, then *newline*, then indent with **two** spaces (this is specified with exactity, on the linked page).

Eclipse doesn't seem to allow such fine-grained configuration. PHPDoc options in Eclipse either allow no indent, like this:

```
* @param array $definition
* The array describing something.
```

Or I can choose this very wide indentation:

```
* @param array $definition
*        The array describing something.
```

Either way, it deviates from the Drupal conventions. And now I can't use the very useful `Source > Format` command, because it will change the comments in the entire file.

What I *actually* want is this:

```
* @param array $definition
*   The array describing something.
```

Is there a hidden configuration parameter somewhere, in an XML file in Eclipse's config?